# kforgeproject.com down

Tags: ros, kforge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this is really something for answers.ros.org, but kforgeproject.com is down for at least 2 months now. Is the project discontinued?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38555/kforgeproject.com-down/) by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 290 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-11**:
Did you mean kforge.ros.org? Is kforgeproject.com a ROS-related site?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-11**:
I think it's the source of the software kforge.ros.org is based on.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-11**:
Ah indeed it appears to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The DNS address is up, but the web site seems to be misconfigured.

You could try contacting the webmaster about getting it fixed.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) on 2012-07-11**:
well, that was my first thought. However, there is no address of the webmaster on the error page...

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-11**:
You might try filing a ticket on the KForge Trac: http://knowledgeforge.net/kforge/trac .

**Comment by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) on 2012-07-11**:
Tried that, cannot create a new account for opening tickets..